# back button not working when i load xib file in stroryboard in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Hi I am very new for iOS. In my project I am loading one xib file in my main storyBoard. I have added one `BannerView` on my storyboard. Afterthat I have added one `BackButton` on that `BannerView`. When I click that button I want push back from my `MainView controller`.

For this goal, I have tried below code but it is not working. Please help me

And here when I am not loading xib file in my main story board. It's working fine using my below code. But when I load xib file in my storyboard, I can't push back. Why this problem i coming. Please help me:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

 UIView *banerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44)];
    banerView.backgroundColor =  [self colorWithHexString:@"EF4836"];
    [mainView addSubview:banerView];

    UIButton *backBtn =[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 15, 15)];
    [backBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [banerView addSubview:backBtn];

-(void)backBtnClicked :(UIButton *)sender{

    [delegate BackbuttonTapped];
```

Comment: are you adding the view in particular view controller in storyboard?

Comment: Please make your post clearly. You said your bode below two times but I just see one code below.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking but if you are using a push segue to get to the new VC you would use `[self.navigationController popToRootViewController animated:YES]`. Otherwise use `[self dismissViewController animated:YES];`. Also you should be using the method `-(IBAction) sender:(UIButton *) sender {}`